# How to reach the value of an object nested within an object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object, boxing

I am somehow producing a C# object that contains another object structure. I am not sure how I can get hold of its content.

I have an array whose value is

```
{object[1,1]}
```

and type

```
object[,]
```

If I unfold it I get:

```
arr[0,0]
```

with value

```
{object[1..1]}
```

and with type

```
object{object[]}
```

and a structure that tells

```
[1]
```

with value (for the sake of argument)

```
myString
```

and with type

```
object{string}
```

I am not sure how I can get hold of the encapsulated string myString that I am searching for.

From the Watch window ((-) means that I unfolded the toggle point (+)):

```
    Name            Value             Type
(-) arr            {object[1,1]}      object[,]
 L  (-) [0,0]      {object[1..1]}     object{object[]}
     L  [1]        "myString"         object{string}

arr[0,0][1]        Cannot apply indexing with [] to an  expression of type 'object'
```

Comment: `{object[1,1]}` and `object{object[]}` are not valid C# types - please post sufficient code such that we can copy-and-paste-and-run that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: _"If I unfold it I get:"_ - what do you mean by "unfold", exactly? That is not a term in C#/.NET.

Comment: @Dai. Well, it is what I get when I debug and run the Watch window. Unfolding means that I toggle open the elements of the structure in the Watch window. A standard object[,], I get in the watch window

Comment: can you share an instance of the object you are trying to inspect in visual studio, as I don't see an issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1CuX.png

Comment: Unfolding means that I toggle open the elements of the structure in the Watch window. 1) For a 'standard' array called arr1 of type object[,], in the watch window, I get, value {object[1,1]} and type object[,]. If I toggle, I get, arr1[0,0] with value "myString" and type object{string}. 2) For the 'non-standard' array called arr2 of type object[,], in the watch window, I get, value {object[1,1]} and type object[,]. If I toggle, I get, arr2[0,0] with value  {object[1..1]}  and type object{object[]} and a further indented toggle [1]  with value "myString" and type object{string}.

Comment: okay? so this looks good to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qehJd.png - alter the instance `objArray` showing your issue

Comment: maybe its easier for us to understand if you share a screenshot, like i am doing - because I still fail to understand where your issue is, and I can't seem to be able to replicate any issue

Comment: Wow, Rand Random, you're quite efficient! You're typing your code faster than I type my questions... Now, in your excerpt, how do I get back to your nested value. Here, when I try, arr[0,0][1] ??? it does not work!!!

Comment: Please describe what you actual goal is, since messing around with objects and arrays in this way is likely not the best way to do whatever it is you are trying to do. do not use `object` unless you really have to. And avoid nesting arrays if you can. Use actual classes to describe whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @Rand Random. Unfortunately, sending a screenshot is beyond my abilities. The error message that I get is the following: arr[0,0][1] "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'".

Comment: Using such an array of objects can be error-prone, and it's generally best practice to use more specific types whenever possible to avoid conversions and potential runtime errors. If you have control over the structure of the object you are using, consider using a more specific type instead of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array seems to be this, based on your last edit:

```
//an array with length 1 and index starts with 1 instead of 0
var mySpecialArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new [] { 1 }, new [] { 1 });
mySpecialArray.SetValue("myString", 1);

var objArray = new object[,]
{
    {mySpecialArray},
};
```

[image]

To get the value `myString` in code behind you can use this

```
Console.WriteLine(((Array)objArray[0,0]).GetValue(1));
```

`objArray[0,0][1]` won't work because you aren't casting `objArray[0,0]` to the type it is (an array), you can't use `[1]` on an instance of type `object`

visual studio is doing underneath magic and will do the cast internally to access `[1]`

Here you can find a demo:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/VHFPmv

Comment: It works like a charm! You are impressively diligent. Many thanks for your very swift and insightful answer. I very much appreciate it.